# Why is the dish combinations in this problem 45 and not 12?

Tags: combinatorics

> At a restaurant, customers can choose up to four side dishes and up to two main courses. If a customer must have at least 1 side dish and 1 main course, how many distinct dinner plate combinations are possible?

The answer is 45. I can only calculate 12.

Call the four side dishes A,B,C,D.
Call the Main courses E and F.

E goes with A,B,C,D.
F goes with A,B,C,D.

8 current.

Now EF goes with A,B,C,D.

12 total.

Comment: It seems that any number of side dishes are also allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible combinations of side dishes: ${4 \choose 1}+{4 \choose 2}+{4 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 4}=4+6+4+1=15$.

Possible combinations of main courses: ${2 \choose 1}+{2 \choose 2}=2+1=3$.

Thus the total number is $15\times3=45$.

Answer (score 3):

If any number of side dishes are allowed, then you may note that there are in total $2^4 - 1 = 15$ combinations of side dishes and $2^2 - 1 = 3$ combinations of main dishes, so a total of $15 \cdot 3 = 45$ total combinations.

Answer (score 3):

You calculated:

1. How many ways you can have one main dish and one side dish. (4 each, 8 total).
2. How many ways you can have two main dishes and one side dish (4 total).

But the problem says **up to four** side dishes. You did not count how many ways you can pick one main dish and two side dishes, two main dishes and two sides dishes, etc.

If you have 4 side dishes, there are $15$ possible choices you can make, $4=\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose one side dish, $6=\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick two-side-dishes options, $4=\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick three side dishes, and $1=\binom{4}{4}$ ways to pick all four side dishes (or just the number of subsets of a 4-element set without the empty set, $2^4-1$). And you have three ways to pick the main dish (one dish in $2$ ways, both dishes in one way).

So you have $15\times 3 = 45$ ways to make both choices.

Answer (score 0):

For variety, here's an inclusion-exclusion approach.  Count all subsets of $4+2$ dishes, subtract the "no side" and "no main" cases, and add back in the "no dish" case that was subtracted twice:
$$2^{4+2} - \binom{4}{0}2^2 - \binom{2}{0}2^4 + \binom{4}{0}\binom{2}{0} = 64 - 4 - 16 + 1 = 45$$